# Explicit solution to a first order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any explicit solution to the following ODE?

$G'(z) =aG(z)+bG(z)^α-c$

$G(0) = d_0 $

Comment: the solution itself depends on the value of alpha, this DE is separable, but the integral form depends on alpha. (as far as i know, which is not that far)

Comment: alpha is around 1, i.e. $ \alpha \in (0.5,5)$

Comment: around 1 or exactly 1?

Comment: if it's 1 the problem would be trivial right?

Comment: yes. the solution in that case is (i think):
$$
\rm G(z)= {[d_0(a+b)-c]e^{(a+b)z}+c \over a+b}
$$